# What screws should I use for my floating Ikea bookshelf?

Tags: drywall, tools, shelving, hanging, drywall-anchor

I recently purchased a floating bookshelf from Ikea. The following links are to the bookshelf and to the assembly directions of the bookshelf.

https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/40103751/

https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/lack-wall-shelf__AA-10128-11_pub.pdf

I will be placing books on these shelves that weigh about 40-45 pounds.

My walls are 1/2inch Drywall.

Originally I wanted to use toggle bolts but I'd rather use something that's less damaging to the wall.

The shelf takes 16 screws so I decided to go with [this threaded anchor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013SBBUGK).

Do you guys think that if I use 16 of these threaded anchors, in the assigned spots indicated by the manufacturer, then the floating bookshelf will be able to hold up the 45 pounds of books that I'll be placing on it?

Comment: "1/4inch Drywall" - are you sure? Not 1/2 inch?

Comment: Sorry, 1/2inch. My mistake.

Comment: It actually uses 8 screws, it alternates between top and bottom holes on the bracket. If you have wood studs a better option would be to screw it into the wood studs, the studs would be spaced about every 16" on your wall. Might require drilling through the bracket. It would be less damaging to the wall than the anchors and hold better.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose I glanced at the PDF but didn't notice that it was actually 8 screws. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: ...using safety-critical anchors from some random non-Amazon seller on Amazon Marketplace, which is basically Alibaba.  What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Honestly,  I don't think there's any fitting you could use that wouldn't pull out from the drywall. What's behind your drywall? You need to fix this to something solid. Even at that, it's quite a lot of weight for this type of shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use anchors for a shelf holding 45 lbs. unless I had no other choice.

Since the shelf is ~ 6 feet long, see if you can position it horizontally so that **at least one of the pairs of holes in the bracket is in front of a stud**. Then use appropriate screws (which type will depend on whether you have metal or wood studs) to mount that pair of holes. Then use anchors for the rest. If you can get two pairs to line up with studs that would be even better - and then I wouldn't bother with anchors in the other 6 pairs of holes. But one pair of screws in studs would hold the shelf up and the anchors in the other locations would keep it straight.

EDIT:

Based on one of the comments I took another look at the wordless instructions. It looks like there are 16 holes in the bracket, probably for simple symmetry - mount either way up and it makes no difference. But the instructions indicate only using 8 screws - two above each of the 3 supports and two lower in between. I recommend using either two in one pair (top/bottom) into one stud plus anchors in as many others as you can (but at a minimum matching at least the 8 total in the instructions) OR at least two screws into two separate studs - but once you are doing that you might as well do 4 - top/bottom in each of two separate studs.

If horizontal positioning requirements (e.g., walls, windows, furniture) don't let you get into any studs then you may want to consider drilling two holes through the bracket in order to match it to two studs. That will void your warranty, but it will be a lot more secure than the anchors. I remember ~ 33 years ago at an office where maintenance came in and installed shelves to support PC tape drives (probably 20 - 30 lbs) and the shelves started coming down pretty fast because the supports were not in studs.

Comment: Thank you for the detail! Just a quick question with regards to drilling into the studs. I came across a video that recommended the exact same thing you're suggesting. To drill in the bracket so it aligns with the studs. If I do drill into the studs, how much weight do you think the shelf will hold? As opposed to using anchors.

I also wanted to add that I have wooden studs. So which screws do you recommend for that?

Comment: If you get screws into at least 2 studs then you can support hundreds of lbs - like kitchen cabinets full of dishes, though any limit based on the shelf itself is important too. 3" is typical.

Comment: Would these suffice?

https://www.amazon.com/Grip-Rite-3CDWS1-3-Inch-Coarse-Drywall/dp/B000BOALP4/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1528919130&sr=8-3&keywords=3%22+stud+screws

Comment: "I recommend using either two in one pair (top/bottom) into one stud plus anchors in as many others as you can (but at a minimum matching at least the 8 total in the instructions) OR at least two screws into two separate studs - but once you are doing that you might as well do 4 - top/bottom in each of two separate studs."

So If I find two studs that align with the bracket, it'd be best to drill 4 screws (top and bottom) into both studs, correct?

Comment: I have seen quite a few recommendations to NOT use ordinary drywall screws for weight-bearing. They are good all-purpose screws, but they are designed to hold drywall to framing and not designed to support a lot of weight and they snap easily (which is good sometimes for "oops" moments - I've had my share). There are "cabinet screws" but plenty others will do. Bracket is 6' long, studs normally 16", so any install will cover at least 3 studs. The question is whether you can align the bracket so that the **existing** holes line up with studs so that you don't have to drill through the bracket.

Comment: How about these?

https://www.amazon.com/GRK-CAB8318HP-Cabinet-HandyPak-Package/dp/B001PCXHR0/ref=sr_1_8?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1528919826&sr=1-8&keywords=cabinet+screws+3+inch

Comment: And I don't mind drilling into the bracket in order get to the studs. It may void the warranty but as long as It can hold the weight I need it to in a safer manner then by all means, I'll do it. Just want to make sure I don't end up waking up to a destroyed shelf.

Comment: Perfect. Just keep in mind that has a T-15 head. Better grip than a Phillips head but you need to have a matching screwdriver bit. To drill through the bracket you will need a bit that (a) can reasonably go through metal and (b) is as wide as the shank of the cabinet screws.

Comment: Yeah I was looking into drilling the bracket the other day as well. I planned on getting this bit. https://www.amazon.com/Neiko-10194A-Titanium-Drill-Speed/dp/B000FZ2UOY/ref=sr_1_3?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1528920182&sr=1-3&keywords=step+drill+bit

Comment: That bit would *probably* work. But I would probably go for something narrower. You probably only need a 1/2", maybe less.

Comment: Sorry for the flooding of links. Lol how about this one? https://www.amazon.com/Neiko-10182A-Titanium-Drill-Speed/dp/B000RP5Z1W/ref=sr_1_3?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1528920664&sr=1-3&keywords=1%2F2%2Bstep%2Bdrill%2Bbit&th=1

Comment: Better - but I'd go with the [1/8-1/2](https://www.amazon.com/Neiko-10182A-Titanium-Drill-Speed/dp/B001CBNPBW/ref=sr_1_3?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1528920664&sr=1-3&keywords=1%2F2%2Bstep%2Bdrill%2Bbit&th=1) unless you think you need others in which case get the 3-pack of all sizes.

Comment: @Lin The standard in homebuilding is that wiring and piping must be protected by steel guard plates if they are within 1-7/8" of the wall surface (give or take).  For wires/pipes through studs, they are to be centered on the stud (stud is 3-1/2", plus the 1/2" drywall of course). Therefore you want to avoid using fasteners longer than that, and stop if you hit something really hard.

Comment: @Harper Which would mean using 2" - 2-1/4" screws instead of 3". My kitchen cabinets added another 3/4" for the cabinet back compared to the shelf bracket.

Comment: @manassehkatz for a 3/4" pipe centered, I assume 15/16" OD (call it 1")  off the 3.5" depth of a 2x4, so that's (3.5-1)/2 = 1.25" penetration into the 2x4 is safe. Plus 1/2" for the drywall = 1-3/4".  Add the thickness of what you're bolting up (1/8" on that bracket?)

Comment: The thickness of this bracket is probably barely 1/4". Would 2 1/2" cabinet screws be a bad idea?

Comment: Based on Harper's comments 2" would be safer.

Comment: okay. Going to go with this screw then. https://www.amazon.com/GRK-CAB82HP-Cabinet-HandyPak-Package/dp/B003VCDG8M/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1528942332&sr=8-3&keywords=cabinet+screws+2+inch

Answer (score 2):

Did they have chalk when you went to school?  Soak newspaper in diluted Elmers glue, wrap it around a stick of chalk, let it dry, that's pretty much what drywall is.  You wouldn't expect that to carry a load, would you?

Your wall probably has wood or metal studs typically 16" on center, sometimes 24",  unless it covers concrete or cinder block.  Of course the IKEA product is **metric**, so we can't expect it to line up with 16/24" centers unless they were rather clever.

The UPPER holes nearest the poles do 90% of the weight carrying.  Either one will do.  The lower holes just keep the unit from flopping upwards. Can't hurt, won't help much.

So find your studs in the walls and figure out how to position the Ikea unit to get the best weight transfer onto the studs. Ideally position it so both outer poles are well supported near studs. **Feel free to drill extra holes** in the IKEA mounting bracket, again the upper holes are the ones doing all the work.  You are drilling into steel, "feeds and speeds" matter, feed is downforce (roughly) and speed is drill speed. When you're in the sweetspot, the drilling is fast and the chips are long.

If you just can't make things line up the way you want, another option is get a piece of hardwood 1" thick (preferably 1.5") and the size of the backing plate.  Position it exactly where you want, attach the hardwood to *every* stud it overlaps, then attach the IKEA mounting bracket to the hardwood as instructions direct but with 1-1/4" screws.  The trick to working with hardwood is pre-drill every hole so it doesn't crack the wood, and drill a slight countersink for the screws into the wall so the Ikea backplate doesn't ride up on their heads. Bonus points if you drill extra holes in the Ikea backplate and run them straight into the stud as well.

Never drill more than 1-3/4" below the wall's surface.  The standard for construction is that wires and pipes must be at least that far away from the wall surface or be guarded by a metal plate to make them difficult to drill through.  If you carelessly use 3" screws and nick a wire, it can break wires or pipes - even electrify the entire shelf!

Comment: I've used a few IKEA products that mount on the wall and their holes lined up with my 16" on center studs, only problem is it limits your ability to center it.